# firefox addon iframe type

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new to firefox and I used JPM to make a firefox addon and submitted it to Mozilla. One reason they gave for rejecting it was the use of iframe elements without a type attribute.

Here are the two situations that an iframe will be loaded.

1. Whenever a page is loaded a content script will be injected to that page and that content script will insert an iframe that acts as the extension's menu. I set the type attribute using jquery append. 
   `$("body").append("<iframe type='content'></iframe>")`
2. Whenever a user clicks a button appended to a youtube video it will load the video through an iframe and display that video on the page with some additional viewing features. The type attribute is being set using vanilla javascript `myIframe.type = 'content'`

Is there something I am completely missing or is how I am setting the type attribute correct?